# Partial Derivative of f with respect to x1

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How can I calculate the partial derivative of a series like e.g. 
$$
a = \sum _{i=1}^n \left(2 x_i^2+z\right)
$$

with respect to $x_{1}, x_{2},... x_{n}$ using Wolfram Mathematica?

I tried it with:

```
D[a, Subscript[x, 1]]
```

But it results in null, which obviously isn't true. I also tried it with:

```
D[a, x]
```

But the result of this isn't what I expected as well. 
I hope that anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't have a particular value of $n$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: What answer are you hoping to obtain?

Comment: No not really. But in my opinion it doesn't matter because all values  $x_{i}$ drop out, except for $x_{1}$ in this case.

Comment: I hope that somebody can tell me if there is a possibility (code) to do this so that you get the right answer for the problem above.

Comment: If you are willing to set `n` to some large number, `D[Sum[2 Subscript[x, i]^2 + z, {i, 1000000}], Subscript[x, 1]]` does what you appear to wish.

Comment: @bb, after all the OP did say the value of $n$ doesn't matter… ;)

Comment: Not clean at all `a = Sum[2 x[i]^2 + z, {i, n}]; 
deriv[i_] := D[a /. n -> i, x[i]]; deriv[3]`